# How to generate a longitudinal binary data with missing at random (MAR)?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation

I want to test the performance of a multiple imputation algorithm for longitudinal binary data. Right now I have applied the algorithm on some real data sets and it turned out promising and then I want to do a simulation to prove that. But the first question for me is how to create this kind of longitudinal binary data with missing mechanism of MAR. Suppose I have a longitudinal data set like this:

```
require(bindata)
set.seed(123)
y<-rmvbin(100, margprob=c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1))
colnames(y)<-c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")
treatment<-sample(1:3, 100, T)
df<-data.frame(cbind(y, treatment))
head(df)
  t1 t2 t3 t4 treatment
1  0  0  1  0         2
2  0  1  0  0         2
3  0  0  1  0         1
4  0  0  0  1         1
5  0  0  0  0         1
6  0  0  0  0         3
```

What I want is, based on `df`, to generate 30% (30 rows) missing values with MAR for the longitudinal outcomes (t1-t4) with, out of the 30 missing rows, 40% (12) missing one of the four observations, 30% (9) missing two, 20% (6) missing three and 10% (3) missing all the four observations. Would somebody have some suggestions or offer an answer. Thanks in advance.